# gulp main.js does not include all js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I'm trying to add a build tool-gulp to my angularjs project but I think I'm doing something wrong with config b/c I keep getting errors like

- require is not defined
- angular is not defined
- or app is not defined (`var app = angular.module("app",[]);` )

I have multiple js files one for service/factories, controllers, and modules. I want to build all my scripts but when I look into main.js it only has the modules defined it does not have any other js files. I am also not sure if I am suppose to copy my html files to my dist folder. I have tried both ways but I keep getting errors like the service is undefined or app is undefined, etc. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong.

This is my code that resides in gulp.js:

```
var gulp=require('gulp');

var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var browserify=require('browserify');
var source=require('vinyl-source-stream');
var jshint=require("gulp-jshint");
var concat=require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    return browserify('./app/app.js').bundle().pipe(source("main.js")).pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/js"));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['scripts'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.js',['scripts']);

});

gulp.task("scripts", function(){
    return gulp.src("app/**/*.js").pipe(concat('main.js')).pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/js"));
});

gulp.task("html",function(){
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.html').pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/html'));
});

gulp.task('clean',function(done){
    del(['./dist'],done);
});

gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: "./",
        port: 4000
    });
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean','scripts','html','connect',"watch"]);
```

In my index.html file:

```
... scripts (like jquery, foundation, etc.)
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/js/main.js"></script>
```

I have been following these tutorials:

```
https://omarfouad.com/ 
http://paislee.io/a-healthy-gulp-setup-for-angularjs-projects/
https://johnpapa.net/angular-and-gulp/
http://blog.angular-university.io/what-every-angular-project-likely-needs-and-a-gulp-build-to-provide-it/
```

Comment: Where and when  you are getting this error?

Comment: @JorawarSingh I get the error when I run my index.html in my browser so just at startup. The index.html file loads all the scripts but the last one which is index.js (contains controllers) and services.js (contains services/factories) produce the errors. It says that the app is undefined so I write require('angular') but then it says require is undefined. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you including your gulpfile in build?